# Python 2.7.8 multiprocessing decorator

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, decorator

I am trying to create a decorator that runs a decorated function in a separate thread. I put those decorators in an extra module to be able to use them from wherever I want.

module "runSeparate":

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import functools

def runInSeparateThread(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def newFun(*args, **kwargs):
        extraThread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        extraThread.start()
        return extraThread
    return newFun


def runInSeparateProcess(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def newFun(*args, **kwargs):
        extraProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        extraProcess.start()
        return extraProcess
    return newFun
```

Note that the two decorator functions are almost identical. One uses threading.Thread and another uses multiprocessing.Process.

In my main function I am calling another function and decorate it with the above decorator.

```
@runSeparate.runInSeparateThread
def test2():
    someOtherModule.test()  # contains only one print command


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = test2()
```

This works fine, but as soon as I change the decorator to

```
 @runSeparate.runInSeparateProcess
```

I get a pickling error:

```
C:\Programme\Python27\python.exe "D:/MKS Integrity/TU/Entwicklung/ControlDeskSkripte/LayoutSkripte/flashLayout.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/MKS Integrity/TU/Entwicklung/ControlDeskSkripte/LayoutSkripte/flashLayout.py", line 72, in <module>
    t = test()
  File "D:\MKS Integrity\TU\Entwicklung\ControlDeskSkripte\HiLSkripte\runSeparate.py", line 27, in newFun
    extraProcess.start()
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programme\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 753, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function test at 0x022AD330>: it's not the same object as __main__.test
```

I would like to use the multiprocessing module and have found many Questions addressing similar topics. Somehow the pickling module is not great at pickling and unpickling functions and the multiprocessing module uses it. On this (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576684-simple-threading-decorator/) page there is an example that creates a threading-decorator. A comment below from Tetsuya Morimoto states that he managed to change it to a multiprocessing decorator, but using the example provided above and his changes I get the same kind of error. It doesn't say what Version of Python they used.

I am using Python 2.7.8 on Windows 7. Is there some way to get around the problem? Am I missing some difference between multiprocessing and threading?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you yet, but this probably has more to do with running on Windows vs. not-Windows.  See [this section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) on Windows limitations with the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Already read that part, but apart from "Also, if you subclass Process then make sure that instances will be picklable when the Process.start method is called.", which I don't really understand I think I stepped around all windows pitfalls.